# Access Dojox.mobile.TextBox value from .js Function?

Tags: dojo, ibm-mobilefirst, dojox.mobile

I am developing a Hybrid application in IBM Worklight .Since i am a newbie in Worklight and Dojo its just a sample application that takes text input value and displays in Alert.I have created a text box, but cant access text box value from javascript function.

My code

```
<input data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.TextBox" id="sampleText" placeHolder="NewYork,USA">
<button data-dojo-type="dojox.mobile.Button" id=testBtn style="float:right;" data-dojo-props="label:'GetData', onClick:function(e){getDataInfo();}" ></button>
```

js Function

```
function getDataInfo(){
    var city = dojox.byId("sampleText").value;
    alert(city);

}
```

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 2 solution.
Edit the function:

```
function getDataInfo(){
    var city = sampleText.value;
    alert(city);
}
```

or add dojo-id to textBox

```
data-dojo-props='id:"sampleText"'>
```

and use this function

```
dojox.byId("sampleText")
```